# time since JVM started

Tags: java, time, jvm

Is there a way to find out the time since the JVM started?

Of course, other than starting a timer somewhere near the beginning of `main`, because in my scenario I am writing library code and the requirement that something be called immediately after startup is a too burdensome.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use this snippet:

```
long jvmUpTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime();
```

or:

```
long jvmStartTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime();
```

This is the **correct** way of retrieving JVM up-time.

For more info see [RuntimeMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html)

Comment: Note that it returns a value in milliseconds, not seconds.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the start time of the JVM in the following code:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
  import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
  ...
  RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
  long uptimeInMillis = runtimeMXBean.getUptime();
```

See more are https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html.

Answer (score 3):

if your jvm program running in linux, you can view the startTime use **ps**

```
ps -p <pid> -o stime,etime
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Java 5, you can use JMX to find this out. Check "[Using the platform MBeanserver](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/mxbeans.html)" to find out more details. The bean you're looking for is the bean called "java.lang:type=Runtime". The attribute StartTime gives you the time the JVM was started and the Uptime attribute tells you the uptime of the JVM.

You can get a reference to the Runtime bean by executing this code:
`ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps worth mentioning that if you don't want to write any code run up jconsole from the java bin directory and click VM Summary and see the Uptime and Process CPU time values.