# Getting the system start time in Java?

Tags: java, java-3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [time since JVM started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817801/time-since-jvm-started)

Is there a way to get the system start time in Java?

I am trying to make some animations using the Alpha class. Alpha is a Java3D API function that models a time-dependent function into [0,1]. An Alpha instance needs to be told how many milliseconds *from the system start* to wait before it begins running. It calls this its triggerTime.

I want to be able to write a line of code that starts the Alpha immediately upon execution of the line. It follows that I need to know how much time has passed since the system started. In other words, I need to set alpha.triggerTime to System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime.

So how do I find this startTime? I know that I could call System.currentTimeMillis() as the first line of my code, but this animation is happening in a thread called by a different class than the one that starts the program, and I don't want to have to pass the startTime around to all of these objects. There has to be a cleaner solution.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: What do you mean by the "system" start time? The time that the _computer_ was turned on, or the time that the _program_ started running?

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks very much for the tip. I did some searches but didn't turn up that thread.

Answer (score 0):

'myAlpha' will start immediately upon execution of following line assuming that 'triggerTime' is '0' (startTime + triggerTime >= currentTime) :

```
myAlpha.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

August, InteractiveMesh