# How to make the JobRegistry contain the job information on server restart in spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-job-monitoring

We have a scenario where whenever a Job is executing STARTED Status the server might crash. In this case to restart the batch I understood from here [Spring Batch resume after server's failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224959/spring-batch-resume-after-servers-failure), that status and end_time column values needs to be updated in batch_job_execution and batch_step_execution from STARTED to FAILED for JobOperator.restart(jobExecutionId) API to work.

But calling this its gives "NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [] was registered" because the jobRegistry map inside JobOperator is empty.

Now how to repopulate JobRegistry with these job informations on server restart, so that we can call JobOperator.restart(jobExecutionId).

Below is my code

```
/** The Test properties. */
  @Autowired
  private TestProperties TestProperties;

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "TestDataSource")

  public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    DataSource TestDBSrc = DataSourceBuilder.create().username(getUsername()).password(getPassword()).url(getUrl()).build();
    if (TestDBSrc != null && TestDBSrc instanceof HikariDataSource) {
      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
      HikariDataSource hikariDatsource = (HikariDataSource) TestDBSrc;
      hikariDatsource.setSchema(getSchema());
    }
    return TestDBSrc;
  }

  private String getSchema() {
    return TestProperties.getValue("spring.datasource.hikari.schema", "");
  }

  private String getUsername() {
    return TestProperties.getValue("spring.datasource.username", "");
  }

  private String getPassword() {
    return TestProperties.getValue("spring.datasource.password", "");
  }

  private String getUrl() {
    return TestProperties.getValue("spring.datasource.jdbc-url", "");
  }

  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(@Qualifier("TestDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
  }

  @Bean(name = "TestBatchJobRepository")
  public JobRepository jobRepository(@Qualifier("TestDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource,
      @Qualifier("transactionManager") JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager) throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(batchTransactionManager);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean(name = "TestBatchJobLauncher")
  public JobLauncher jobLauncher(@Qualifier("TestBatchJobRepository") JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
    TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
  }

  @Bean (name = "TestBatchJobExplorer")
  public JobExplorer jobExplorer(@Qualifier("TestDataSource") DataSource dataSource,@Qualifier("transactionManager")JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager) throws Exception {
      final JobExplorerFactoryBean bean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
      bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
      bean.setTransactionManager(batchTransactionManager);
      bean.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
      bean.setJdbcOperations(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
      bean.afterPropertiesSet();
      return bean.getObject();
  }
  
  @Bean (name ="TestBatchJobRegistry")
  public JobRegistry jobRegistry() throws Exception {
    return new MapJobRegistry();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(@Qualifier("TestBatchJobRegistry") JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
      JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
      postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
      return postProcessor;
  }
  
  @Bean (name = "TestBatchJobOperator")
  public JobOperator jobOperator(@Qualifier("TestBatchJobLauncher") JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Qualifier("TestBatchJobRepository") JobRepository jobRepository,
          @Qualifier("TestBatchJobRegistry") JobRegistry jobRegistry, @Qualifier("TestBatchJobExplorer") JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
      final SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
      jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
      jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
      jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
      jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
      return jobOperator;
  }
}
```

Here since I am using the default in-memory map

```
@Bean (name ="TestBatchJobRegistry")
  public JobRegistry jobRegistry() throws Exception {
    return new MapJobRegistry();
  }
```

Its getting cleared on server restart.

Update 24/10/2023 :
[image: Screenshots of spring batch tables]

On server restart,
[image: Debug on server restart]

The jobregistry is empty.
Tried,

```
 public void restart(@Qualifier("febpBatchJobExplorer") JobExplorer jobExplorer,@Qualifier("febpBatchJobRepository") JobRepository jobRepository, @Qualifier("febpBatchJobOperator") JobOperator jobOperator){
      try {
          List<String> jobNames=jobExplorer.getJobNames();
          for(String jobName:jobNames)
          {
              List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobName,0,1);// this will get one latest job from the database
              if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(jobInstances)){
                 JobInstance jobInstance =  jobInstances.get(0);
                 List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance);
                 if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(jobExecutions)){
                     for(JobExecution execution: jobExecutions){
                         // If the job status is STARTED then update the status to FAILED and restart the job using JobOperator.java
                         if(execution.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.STARTED) || execution.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.FAILED)){ 
                             execution.setEndTime(LocalDateTime.now());
                             execution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);                               
                             execution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);                               
                             jobRepository.update(execution);
                             jobOperator.restart(execution.getId());
                         }
                     }
                 }
              }
          } 
      }catch (Exception e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

But again jobOperator.restart(execution.getId()) is failing due to empty jobRegistry.

It fails at below spring batch code,
[image]

**Update 27/10/2023 :** Providing a sample application to reproduce the issue,
https://github.com/PSHREYASHOLLA/SamplebatchApplication.

Its a maven project, so you can call mvn install, it will create \target\SamplebatchApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.
Now you can start it like any springboot app(Liquibase enabled), java -jar SamplebatchApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

If you see application.properties file we are pointing it to a postgres database. All our batch configurationhttps://github.com/PSHREYASHOLLA/SamplebatchApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/postgresql/model/FEBPDBConfig.java.

Please start the batch process by calling rest post API ,
http://localhost:8080/batch/trigger-or-resume-application-batch-job
JSON body {
"appRestartJobExecutionId": ""
}
If we call this with empty appRestartJobExecutionId, the flow is like below,
com.example.postgresql.controller.BatchController.triggerOrResumeApplicationBatchJobByB2E() --->com.example.postgresql.model.FebpApplicationJobServiceImpl.triggerApplicationBatchJob() --> We do JobLauncher.run(). Now this job will read 50 records from febp_emp_detail_test as part of reader and as part of writer writes the updated records to febp_emp_tax_detail_test. This is a happy flow.

Now if you call the above API and say after 5 seconds you kill the server, only partial commit will happen into febp_emp_tax_detail_test and the batch status will be in STARTED state. Now say I restart the server and call the same post API with failed job execution ID it will now call  om.example.postgresql.controller.BatchController.triggerOrResumeApplicationBatchJobByB2E() --->com.example.postgresql.model.FebpApplicationJobServiceImpl.resumeApplicationBatchJob() ---> jobOperator.restart(failedBatchExecutionId); Here the restart API fails due to empty jobRegistry.

**Update 02/11/2023:**

After changing my job to a bean as suggested by Mahmoud Ben Hassine, I am able to restart job. But now after restart a new Job execution starts and says completed but it fails to process the data. If the job runs on a single thread it processes all the data, but if its multi thread it does not do anything.
Please check https://github.com/PSHREYASHOLLA/SamplebatchApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/postgresql/model/EmployeeTaxCalculationBatchConfig.java

Line 60, Step step = new StepBuilder("FEBP_EMP_TAX_CALCULATION_STEP", jobRepository)
.<EmployeeDetail, EmployeeTaxDetail>chunk(5, transactionManager)
.reader(reader.getPagingItemReader()).processor(itemProcessor).writer(itemWriter).taskExecutor(actStmntTaskExecutor())
.**throttleLimit(50)**.build();

Here if throttleLimit is 1 it process records after restart, but if its multithreaded it does not process remaining records in my sample table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not be the case since you have registered a `JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor`. This is the bean post processor that populates the job registry every time the Spring application context is (re)started.

***EDIT: Answer updated after providing a minimal example***

The issue is that the job is not declared as a bean [here](https://github.com/PSHREYASHOLLA/SamplebatchApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/postgresql/model/EmployeeTaxCalculationBatchConfig.java#L56), it is rather the configuration class (which is obviously not of type `Job`) that is declared as a bean of that name [here](https://github.com/PSHREYASHOLLA/SamplebatchApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/postgresql/model/EmployeeTaxCalculationBatchConfig.java#L24). Therefore the `JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor` does not find the job and does not register it in the registry.

The Job should be registered as a bean in the application context for the `JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor` to post process the bean and register it in the registry.

Comment: After server restart the jobRegistry  is empty. What all status jobs are populated by  JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor ?

Comment: If you restart the server, the Spring application context will be recreated, and therefore the `JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor`will repopulate the registry with jobs.

Comment: Is the above code which I have shared is correct where we are initializing JobRegistry to a new map everytime on server startup , Bean (name ="TestBatchJobRegistry")
  public JobRegistry jobRegistry() throws Exception {
    return new MapJobRegistry();}  and then we have  @Bean
  public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(Qualifier("TestBatchJobRegistry") JobRegistry jobRegistry) {JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new Job RegistryBeanPostProcessor();postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);returnposProcessor;} As I am getting empty jobRegistry everytime.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Yes the code is correct. If you restart the server, a new Spring application context will be loaded, and the map registry will be repopulated with by the JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor, just like a fresh start.

Comment: Thanks for code confirmation please check my update above in issue body. I have updated screenshots of batch_job_execution table and the debug in JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor during server startup. Its still empty please let me know what to change?

Comment: Ok let's clear out a few things because I think we are not on the same page. What do you mean by "server restart"? Are you restarting a Tomcat or something like that? Are you sure the Spring Application context is restarted? If you want to help you efficiently, please take some time to share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and the instructions you use to start and restart the app that leads to an empty job registry.

Comment: 1) Restart -> Spring boot application restart(Tomcat), which contains our batch job implementation. 2) Are you sure the Spring Application context is restarted?--> The debug screenshots are when the server is restarted after its crashed.   Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Can you please help me to proceed?

Comment: No, sorry. Unfortunately I do not see the cause of this issue by just looking at the code and screenshots.

Comment: Let me add the sample application where you can reproduce. Have updated  above, please provide your inputs.

Comment: Can you please provide your inputs?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the repo. I will take a look.

Comment: @ShreyasHollaP I found the issue and updated the answer accordingly. Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my jobRegistry issue. But after I call restart API data is not getting processed, have updated above please help.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: That's a different issue and is not related to the restart anymore. It is related to the throttle limit value (50) which should be lower than the pool size (also 50). This is mentioned in the javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/5.0.2/api/org/springframework/batch/repeat/support/TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.html#setThrottleLimit(int): `when used with a thread pooled TaskExecutor the thread pool might prevent the throttle limit actually being reached (so make the core pool size larger than the throttle limit if possible).`

Comment: I have raised separate thread for discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432989/restarting-a-job-after-server-crash-is-not-processing-the-unprocessed-data. Can you please tell so are you referring to SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(50);? This should be less than throttleLimit?