# How to log WebLogic startup time?

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

When Tomcat starts, its last log line is as following:

```
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 20147 ms
```

Which is clearly a *feature* to log on purpose the startup time in milliseconds, really useful as official stat.

When WebLogic starts however, its last log line is:

```
<WebLogicServer> <CIS1405986> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: \
'10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> \
 <5097d97d-cb6a-41aa-b418-717a3f768636-0000000d> <1479382972090> \
<[severity-value: 32] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > \
<BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>
```

Acknowledging the `RUNNING` status, but not providing any info concerning its startup time.

**Question**: is there any way to make WebLogic log its startup time or find it anywhere in its console?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in the weblogic console; even for the various managed instances.

Just go under Domain Structure to: Environment >> Servers >> Monitoring.

You can see the details under: **Activation Time**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all fails, and independent of WebLogic, you can deploy a WAR that queries the JVM uptime in an init class and emits that to the log, and does nothing else. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/817835/1037626

Answer (score 0):

In the WLS console, go to Environment--> Servers --> Admin Server. Click on Monitoring tab and then to General. You can see Activation time, which tells you when the server is started.

MBean Attribute:
ServerRuntimeMBean.ActivationTime